# Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ IGoogleMapTrackerProps }> & Readonly<{ chirldren?: ReactNode; }>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sharepoint

[image]

I'm am a beginner developer in SharePoint and I stuck With Google map. I install google-maps-react but there is one error show me. I don't know how to solve it... Plz, let me know about this solution... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well it is telling you that google is not a property in the IGoogleMapTrackerProps. You specified that you will have props of IGoogleMapTrackerProps, but you are providing google prop instead.

If that is intentional, you can extend the IGoogleMapTrackerProps to include google for example:

```
interface Props extends IGoogleMapTrackerProps  {
    google: // type of google
}
```

and use the Props interface instead of IGoogleMapTrackerProps in class definition.